# Attempting to use jQuery slider in multiple instances on the same page

Tags: jquery, slideshow

So I've attempted to create a way to have multiple widgets (will have possibly 10-20+) that use the same exact effect. The problem I'm having now is that it's stairstepping the div positioning. Is there any way to reset the positions for each to stay within the container? I've removed "overflow:hidden" so that you can see the positioning of the boxes. Any help would be great. I believe it's something combined between my js/html/css. Unsure how to go about this. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/57wzt/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Effects
    defaultWidth    = 250; //pixels
    transition      = 375; //millisecond

    //Generate ID for each box

    //Reset Margin, Set Margin (for each div content)
    function resetMargin(width) {

        divLeftMargin   = 0;

        $('.widget-block').each(function() {

            thisLeftMargin  = divLeftMargin + 'px';
            $(this).css('margin-left', thisLeftMargin);
            divLeftMargin   = divLeftMargin + width;

        });
    }

    //Reset DIV Margins
    resetMargin(defaultWidth);

    //Find sub-menu for each menu and show the arrow
    $('.menu a').each(function() {

        thisHref    = $(this).attr('href');

        if($(thisHref).length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('has-child');
        }

    });

    //User Menuclick
    $('.menu a').click(function(event) {

        //Disable default action
        event.preventDefault();

        //Initialize all variable and object
        selectedDiv         = $(this).attr('href');
        selectedMargin      = $(selectedDiv).css('margin-left');
        selectedParent      = $(this).parents('.widget-block');
        sliderMargin        = $('.slider').css('margin-left');
        slidingMargin       = (parseInt(sliderMargin) - defaultWidth) + 'px';


        //If selected menu has sub menu
        if(selectedMargin.length > 0) {

            //Add 'Back' button to DIV
            $(selectedDiv).children('.header').prepend('<span class="back"></span>').bind('click', function () {

                //And bind action to this button
                selectedParent  = $(this).parents('.widget-block');
                sliderMargin    = - (parseInt(selectedParent.css('margin-left')) - defaultWidth) + 'px';
                $(this).parents('.slider').animate({marginLeft: sliderMargin}, transition);
            });

            //If selected div content's margin more than or equal than default width
            if((parseInt(selectedMargin) - defaultWidth) >= defaultWidth) {

                //Move the selected div content after the menu's div content, reset and set all div content margin and slide them
                selectedParent.after($(selectedDiv));
                resetMargin(defaultWidth);
                $(this).parents('.slider').animate({marginLeft: slidingMargin}, transition);

            } else {

                $(this).parents('.slider').animate({marginLeft: slidingMargin}, transition);

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't appear to show the problem (or I don't understand it). Maybe try to simplify.

Comment: you need to reset divLeftMargin in resetMargin for each .slider like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/57wzt/2/)

Comment: @AbrahamUribe I must be brain farting. That helped a ton!!! Thanks!

Comment: also you need to change ids to be unique or use classes like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/57wzt/3/)